# Powershell Script to create folder by week number for 2022

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a folder by week number so far i am able to create it for the current week however i would like to create it for the entire year i.e. 2022 under the respective months i.e. March April etc.. All the week number folders should be created inside these folders.

````
$currentweek = "{0:d1}" -f ($(Get-Culture).Calendar.GetWeekOfYear((Get-Date),[System.Globalization.CalendarWeekRule]::FirstFourDayWeek, [DayOfWeek]::Monday))
$destFolder = New-Item -Path C:\C:\Users\MAdmin\Documents\VA05\2022\March\Week_$currentweek -Type Directory -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue ```
````

Comment: `-Path C:\C:\Users`?

Comment: Also, grouping by month *and* week number seems unnecessarily complicated to me. What do you gain from that? I'd suggest you do one or the other.

Comment: Sorry thats a typo it should be C:\Users

Comment: Thanks Tomalak, you are right i will stick to Week numbers only, but how do i create folders for all the week numbers in a year.

Comment: Doing calendar weeks *correctly* in .NET (and PowerShell is .NET) is surprisingly complicated. The `.GetWeekOfYear()` method does **NOT** correctly implement the ISO 8601 calendar week rules, which are in effect for e.g. Germany. For example, 29. December 2008 is supposed to be calendar week #1, but .NET calculates week #53. The answer pretty much depends on how much you depend on formal correctness. If it doesn't matter, you could just as well run a loop `foreach ($w in 1..53) {...}` and get on with your life.

Comment: My approach would be to find when the first week of the year begins, then loop, adding 7 days to that date with each iteration (giving you the start of each week to calculate week and month from), until you end up with week 1 again (which is week 1 of the next year, the end of the loop).

Comment: @DocZerø That's useless as long as there is no reliable way to calculate the calendar week from a date. And `.GetWeekOfYear()` is not correct. Overall, I'd recommend the OP to re-think the idea of segmenting the data by calendar week. Finding a way to get that right feels like heavily diminishing returns.

Comment: @Tomalak According to the docs, [`ISOWeek.GetYear`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.isoweek.getyear?view=net-6.0) and [`ISOWeek.GetWeekOfYear`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.isoweek.getweekofyear?view=net-6.0) solve the issue with ISO 8601 ([blog post](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=160851)), starting from .NET 3.0. Regardless, dates are not a trivial subject, even though they might seem like it.

Comment: @DocZerø Then the docs are wrong. You can verify that yourself - for example, 29. December 2008 is calendar week 53 according to .NET, and in reality it's part of calendar week 1 of the following year.

Comment: @Tomalak `Get-Date -UFormat %V` seems to work ... even for this special date ;-)  `Get-Date '29.12.2008' -UFormat %V` returns a `01` on my German system

Comment: @Olaf It does not on mine. `Get-Culture` returns "1031 / de-DE / German (Germany)", `$PSVersionTable`shows a `PSVersion` of 5.1.19041.1320, a `CLRVersion` of 4.0.30319.42000. `Get-Date '29.12.2008' -UFormat %V` returns 53.

Comment: Ooops ... my bad ... I tested it on version 7.2.  On version 5.1 it returns 53 as well.  Sorry.  ... if that's not the perfect occasion to move to version 7  :-D ;-)

Comment: `[System.Globalization.ISOWeek]::GetWeekOfYear('2008-12-29')` returns `1` in PS 7. So it seems the docs are correct. The same statement returns an exception when run in Windows PowerShell since that is based on the full .NET Framework which in current versions does not yet support this API.

Comment: @DocZerø PS 7 is not standard, last I checked. (and not fully feature-compatible to standard PS, either...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you would like to create a folder tree of week numbers in the year 2022, because as you have commented in reply of [Tomalak's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71690904/powershell-script-to-create-folder-by-week-number-for-2022#comment126699441_71690904), creating these weeknumber subfolders inside Monthname folders can hardly be done correctly since weeknumbers can overlap months.

To do this, I would use a helper function to obtain the first Thursday of the first week in the year. (ISO 8601 dictates that week 1 starts with the week that has a Thursday in it):

```
function Get-FirstThursday {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, Position = 0)]
        [int]$Year = [DateTime]::Now.Year,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, Position = 1)]
        [int]$WeekNumber = [CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear([DateTime]::Now, 
                           [System.Globalization.CalendarWeekRule]::FirstFourDayWeek, 
                           [DayOfWeek]::Monday)
    )

    $january1  = [DateTime]::new($Year,1,1,0,0,0,[System.DateTimeKind]::Local)
    $offset    = [int]([DayOfWeek]::Thursday - $january1.DayOfWeek)

    $thursday1 = $january1.AddDays($offset)
    # ISO 8601
    $week1     = [CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear($thursday1, 
                 [System.Globalization.CalendarWeekRule]::FirstFourDayWeek, 
                 [DayOfWeek]::Monday)

    if($week1 -le 1) { $WeekNumber -= 1 }
    # return the date for the first Thursday of the week in the given year
    $thursday1.AddDays($WeekNumber * 7)
}
```

Having that function on top of the script, you can create the folders like:

```
$destination = 'C:\Users\MAdmin\Documents\VA05'
$year = (Get-Date).Year  #  2022

# get the first Thursday of week 1 in the given year
$thursday = Get-FirstThursday -Year $year -WeekNumber 1

# keep adding 7 days to this first Thursday until we reach next year
# create weeknumber subfolders (most years 52, some years 53)
$week = 0
while ($thursday.Year -eq $year) {
    $thursday = $thursday.AddDays(7)
    $week++
    # create a subfolder for this weeknumber
    $targetFolder = Join-Path -Path $destination -ChildPath ('{0}\{1:D2}' -f $year, $week)
    $null = New-Item -Path $targetFolder -ItemType Directory -Force
}
```